# Is it true equation written on C #?

Tags: c#, math

The equation is:

[image]

Is it true I have written?

```
Double x = 14.26
Double y = -1.22
Double z = 3.5 * Math.Pow(10.0, -2)
Double t;

t = ( 2 * Math.Cos( x - Math.PI / 6 ) ) / ( 0.5 + Math.Pow( Math.Sin( y ), 2 ) ) * ( (1 + Math.Pow( z, 2 ) ) / ( 3 - Math.Pow( z, 2 ) / 5 ) );
```

Because the result does not coincide with the above desired result -- t = 0,188451240697501, and I need to t deduced 0.564849.

Comment: What about `y`? Is this in degrees or radians?

Comment: I suggest computing the numerators and denominators separately to make your expression easier to understand.

Comment: @GhostBasenji sorry but I think that Ofiris answer contains an error.. he does 1 + (Math.Pow(z, 2) and then divide all for (3-Math.Pow(z, 2)/5).. but this is an error if you see the algebric expression you posted, because you have add 1 to (Math.Pow(z, 2) / (3-Math.Pow(z, 2)/5)). The whole your previous part of expression is correct

Comment: @Dai excuse me, but it is you to have changed the confirmation about this question, please?

Comment: @CiroCorvino I don't understand.

Comment: @Dai nothing.. I just only asking if you had been you to have removed the confirmation on my answer because I had seen that the question was edited by you. But then I saw that you had edited the question on november... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one error it is here:

```
((1 + Math.Pow(z, 2)) / (3-Math.Pow(z, 2)/5))
```

you should do:

```
(1 + (Math.Pow(z, 2) / (3-Math.Pow(z, 2)/5)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Double x = 14.26, y = -1.22, z = 3.5 * Math.Pow(10.0, -2), t;
    t = (2*Math.Cos(x-Math.PI/6))/(0.5+Math.Pow(Math.Sin(y), 2)) * ( 1 + (Math.Pow(z, 2)) / (3-Math.Pow(z, 2)/5));

    Console.WriteLine(t); // 0.5648...
```

You have parenthesis issue, change `((1 + Math.Pow(z, 2))` to `(1 + (Math.Pow(z, 2))`, the addition of 1 should be calculated after the division.

Also, consider computing the numerators and denominators separately.

Comment: This answer contains an obvious calculation error compared to the algebraic form of the expression given in the question. Because "1" is added to "(Math.pow (z, 2))" and then divided by "(3 - (Math.pow (z, 2) / 5))". While the correct calculation consists of the sum of "1" with the result of division between "(Math.pow (z, 2)) and (3 - (Math.pow (z, 2) / 5))".